# NodeJS download images from authenticated external source in bulk / batches

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

**Overview:**

I have the task of migrating some content out of a legacy tool before we lose access to it. Specifically, there are email renders generated for marketing and I need to download those email preview images from this system. There are no internal APIs or support from the product side that will help get those images.

**Approach:**

The image preview URL accepts 3 parameters. The `ID` of the image, and the `height` and `width` attribute. This website requires authentication, so when I log in, I take the cookie/headers it generates and drop them into my code so that I can send the headers along with the `fetch`. For this, I am using nodeJS and `node-fetch` to make the callout to the URL. It then writes the image to disk and iterates through the list.

**Question:**

We have several thousand of these email previews/images that need to be downloaded. Currently, my code iterates through one at a time which is not very scalable. Is there a way to use concurrency with something like `fetch` so I can have it be downloading multiple images at a time, with some upper limit? Any thoughts on a better approach to tackling this? It's only a one-time situation for this migration, so I'm just looking for the most efficient way to do this.

**Code:**

```
// Includes
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

// Vars
const jobIDs = [];
const imageWidth = 1024;
const imageHeight = 2000;
const jobFileName = '500.csv';
const cookie = "xt_0d95e=!O34QVojQ....redacted"


let currentIteration = 0;
let currentJobId = '';

/**
 * Read our data list to process
 */
fs.createReadStream(jobFileName)
    .pipe(csv({
        delimiter: ','
    }))
    .on('data', (data) => jobIDs.push(data))
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log(jobIDs.length + ' Job IDs loaded from list.');
        checkNext();
    });

/**
 * Check to see if we have more JobIds to process
 */
function checkNext() {

    // Do we have more Job ID's to run?
    if (currentIteration < jobIDs.length) {

        // If we have another JobID, set it to the current variable and continue scraping
        if (jobIDs[currentIteration].JobID != null) {
            currentJobId = jobIDs[currentIteration].JobID;
            scrape();
        }

    } else {

        // Debug
        console.log('Complete - Downloaded [' + jobIDs.length + ' Emails]');

    }
}

/**
 * Iterate over each JobId, make a call-out for the image, and save it
 */
function scrape() {

    // Debug
    console.log('Fetching Job ID: ' + currentJobId);

    // Fetch
    fetch(`https://website.com/Content/Email/EmailThumbnail.aspx?jid=${currentJobId}&w=${imageWidth}&h=${imageHeight}`, {
            "headers": {
                "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
                "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
                "cache-control": "max-age=0",
                "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
                "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
                "sec-fetch-site": "none",
                "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
                "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
                "cookie": cookie
            },
            "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
            "body": null,
            "method": "GET",
            "mode": "cors"
        })
        .then(res => {

            // Store the image and rename it to the Job ID
            const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`./images/${currentJobId}.png`);
            res.body.pipe(dest);

            // Debug
            let output = '\n' + currentJobId;
            fs.appendFileSync('./debug.txt', output);

            // Check for more
            currentIteration++;
            checkNext();
        });

}
```